# get attributeby is not working

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
        String a=driver.findElement(By.id(locator))).getAttribute("value");

        System.out.println("the value is "+ a);

        Log.info(" Required object is present in the applicaiton"+ object);

        <p locale="" isnumeric="false" basetype="String" class="outputText twControl twOutputText" id="InputText12">**MANTPLAP29102014100955627**</p>
```

I need to get the `MANTPLAP29102014100955627` value from the above HTML code.
Please help..

Comment: In your case, you will just need to `getText()` of the element. You only need to use `.getAttribute()` when you need to get an inline atribute, for example, `getAttribute("basetype")`

Comment: When i use basetype.. it's returns String.

Comment: That's correct because the inline attribute of your element are `basetype="String"`. So to get the TEXT of the element, use `getText()`. It's text because it is not an inline attribute and is found between the `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
driver.findElement(By.id(locator))).getText();
```

**Edit**

There is a difference between getAttribute and getText methods

Consider an html tag like this

```
<input type = "text" id = "id" name = "bird">Peagon</input>
```

Now using
    `driver.findElement(By.id("id"))).getAttribute("name")` will return  value as `bird` (which is the value of attribute 'name')
and using

`driver.findElement(By.id(locator))).getText();` will return a value as `Peagon` (Text between the starting  and closing `<input>` tags)

Comment: Perfect Abhishek..it gives correct value. thanks for sharing anwser.

Comment: there is a scenarios, when i get the string, i need to search in the other page, that should say entered text is not present. please help me code

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.